# Find New Name in computer after rename (before restart)

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I'm working on an application that needs to find the correct computer name from the windows OS after being renamed.

There are a lot of methods to find the current name of which I am using the registry Hostname. `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters : Hostname`, as this is one of the few which has a Case Sensitive value rather than full capital letters.

I am now looking to do the same and find what the system will be renamed to after a restart. I have found a key which has this information in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName : ComputerName` but this is also fully capital letters.

Is there a key somewhere I can use that gets the new computer name as input e.g. `TestComputer` without restarting?

I am using python to get these keys into my application (winreg module) so if there are python specific ways those are preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NV Hostname` in the same registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ : NV Hostname
```

is the host name that the computer will take when it is restarted. It is also case-aware.